Can you create new objects with jdb print?
jdb's print allows evaluation of expression, but I'm not sure if it's possible to create new objects that way. Any new seems to return just null, e.g.:
Thread-0[1] print new java.lang.String("12")
Thread not suspended
 new java.lang.String("12") = null

(That's with Java [Open] JDK 8.412 on Linux, if it makes any diff.)
Any ideas what's going on there? And is it possible to work around that an still instantiate new objects from within jdb?

(I've added the multithreading and JVM tags because the issue wasn't as simple as it first seemed, but is related to threading and new apparently not finishing if all threads are suspended. See my self-answer that has a partial workaround, for details.)

Behavior is exactly the same on Windows with Oracle's JDK 8.411.

The issue appears to be with suspended threads. On a simpler example, where a thread is "running (at breakpoint)" it does work to call new from jdb (print) itself.
main[1] print new java.lang.String("aasdf")
 new java.lang.String("aasdf") = "aasdf"

main[1] threads
Group system:
  (java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler)0x162 Reference Handler cond. waiting
  (java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread)0x161  Finalizer         cond. waiting
  (java.lang.Thread)0x160                         Signal Dispatcher running
Group main:
  (java.lang.Thread)0x1                           main              running (at breakpoint)

However (interestingly), on this simpler example, if I suspend the threads, jdb actually first prints nothing (it seemed to me to hang, but it just prints nothing) on the first print call after suspend, but on a 2nd one prints null.
hangs when trying to new something rather than return null.
main[1]  suspend
All threads suspended.
main[1] print new java.lang.String("aasdf")
<< prints nothing! >>
main[1] print new java.lang.String("aasdf")
Thread not suspended
 new java.lang.String("aasdf") = null


And for the supreme weirdness: if you then re-set a breakpoint and continue, the print that seemed to print nothing then comes back from the past/dead and prints something! (It was itself apparently suspended, somehow.)
main[1] stop in hmmm.main
Set breakpoint hmmm.main
main[1] cont
>  new java.lang.String("aasdf") = "aasdf"

I'm not sure if these are bugs in jdb. Anyways, print new ... seem to not work with suspended threads, but does work when "running (at breakpoint)". So, making sure the thread is "running (at breakpoint)" is a partial workaround.
I've also tested if it makes any diff if you do print new ... or have a static wrapper method that returns the new String ... (and you do just print wrap() from jdb then) but it makes no difference, behavior-wise. So, the issue seem to be with creating new objects when threads are suspended. Perhaps there's a JVM thread that needs to run for new to complete. (Someone who knows more about JVM internals can perhaps chime in on this.)

The gory details why it works quirkily like this are in the JDI invokeMethod which is (almost) certainly how that is done:

The method invocation will occur in the specified thread. Method invocation can occur only if the specified thread has been suspended by an event which occurred in that thread. Method invocation is not supported when the target VM has been suspended through VirtualMachine.suspend() or when the specified thread is suspended through ThreadReference.suspend().

So, only 'synchronous'/internal suspends (i.e. breakpoints) from the same thread can eval expressions properly in the target VM. Suspending threads 'externally' with suspend (in jdb) breaks expression evaluation (via invokeMethod) in some cases.
Also, it gets even hairier if other threads are involved in the invoke/call:

By default, all threads in the target VM are resumed while the method is being invoked if they were previously suspended by an event or by VirtualMachine.suspend() or ThreadReference.suspend(). This is done to prevent the deadlocks that will occur if any of the threads own monitors that will be needed by the invoked method. Note, however, that this implicit resume acts exactly like ThreadReference.resume(), so if the thread's suspend count is greater than 1, it will remain in a suspended state during the invocation and thus a deadlock could still occur. By default, when the invocation completes, all threads in the target VM are suspended, regardless their state before the invocation. It is possible that breakpoints or other events might occur during the invocation. This can cause deadlocks as described above. It can also cause a deadlock if invokeMethod is called from the client's event handler thread. In this case, this thread will be waiting for the invokeMethod to complete and won't read the EventSet that comes in for the new event. If this new EventSet is SUSPEND_ALL, then a deadlock will occur because no one will resume the EventSet. To avoid this, all EventRequests should be disabled before doing the invokeMethod, or the invokeMethod should not be done from the client's event handler thread.

The latter probably explains why print new hangs and then eventually wakes up and finishes the print, when threads were suspended with suspend (instead of breakpoint[s]) in jdb.

I rarely use the command line tool gdb but I know from debugging with Eclipse that evaluating expressions does not work when suspending a thread but when you just do one step after suspending the thread, it will behave like being at a breakpoint after the step and evaluating expressions will work then. This unfortunately won’t help when the suspended thread is at a wait() or something similar where it can’t advance one step.

@Holger: I guess that's with the JDK JVM due to the same limitations. Does the OpenJ9 (which also comes with Eclipse IIRC) have the same limitations?

There are different bundles for Eclipse. Mine does not include OpenJ9…
